# Fetching Values from database & Setting it in Spinner

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-spinner

I have developed a spinner which updates the value from a database.

Initially I have set the value to `Q`. When I change the value from `Q` to `C` it is updated in the database and the change is reflected in the Spinner.

When I go back and return to the same page the old value `Q` is being displayed. How do I solve this?

**Code** (also on [pastie.org](http://pastie.org/4677894))

```
package com.androidlogin.ws;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class InsertionExample extends Activity {
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://xcart.com";
    private final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8089/XcartLogin/services/update?wsdl";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xcart.com/insertData";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "insertData";
    Button btninsert;
    String selectedItem;

    static final String KEY_NAME = "orderid";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.change_status);
      /*  Intent in = getIntent();

        // Get XML values from previous intent
        String orderid = in.getStringExtra(KEY_NAME);

        // Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        lblName.setText(orderid); */


        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        btninsert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_insert1);
        btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent in = getIntent();
                 String orderid = in.getStringExtra(KEY_NAME);

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
                unameProp.setName("Status");//Define the variable name in the web service method
                unameProp.setValue(selectedItem);//Define value for fname variable
                unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable

                request.addProperty(unameProp);
                PropertyInfo idProp =new PropertyInfo();
                idProp.setName("Orderid");//Define the variable name in the web service method
                idProp.setValue(orderid);//Define value for fname variable
                idProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
                request.addProperty(idProp);



                  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                  envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                  HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                  try{
                   androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                      SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

                     TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                      result.setText(response.toString());
                 }
               catch(Exception e){

               }
                  }
        });

        //attach the listener to the spinner
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
        //Dynamically generate a spinner data 
        createSpinnerDropDown();

    }

    //Add animals into spinner dynamically
    private void createSpinnerDropDown() {

        //get reference to the spinner from the XML layout
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        //Array list of animals to display in the spinner
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("Q");
        list.add("P");
        list.add("F");
        list.add("I");
        list.add("C");

        //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        //set the view for the Drop down list
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //set the ArrayAdapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //attach the listener to the spinner
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

    }






    public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

             selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

           }


        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question. If the link breaks your question will become worthless to future visitors looking for the answer to a similar question.

Comment: You have to set your spinner from the value stored in database only,instead of setting default value Q(first value in your list).For that,you need to fetch records in onCreate() and set value to your spinner.